# Python Flask URL route is not working when using URL_Prefix

Tags: python, flask

When I added a `URL_PREFIX='/my-app'` in `app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/my-app')` , and click a button to send a POST request, it will route to `/process` instead of `/my-app/process` and cause me to getting 404 Not Found.

It suppose to route to `/my-app/process` instead of `/process`

However, if I change to `URL_PREFIX ='/'` , it works fine when I clicked the button.

How can I make it route to `/my-app/process`?

Here is example of **main.py**

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

****init**.py** where I add my `URL_prefix`

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app= Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'GFTTR687YVXTR5GF96R4EDF'

    from .views import views

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/my-app')

    return app
```

and my **views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request,jsonify,redirect,url_for,session,Flask
from json import dumps
import pandas as pd

views = Blueprint('create_flow_chart', __name__)


@views.route('/')
def home():

  #do something
   
    return render_template("create-flow-chart.html",category=category, steps =dumps(text),product=product)


@views.route('/process', methods=['POST','GET'])
def send_selection():

    
    
   #do something
   


    
    return redirect(url_for('.do_create',steps=steps))


@views.route('/create')
def do_create():
    
 #do something

    return render_template("create-flow-chart.html",category=category, steps = dumps(steps),product=product)
```

my **create-flow-chart.html** that shows where is the button is

```
<h2>TOOL</h2> 
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label>Product</label>
                <form method="POST" action="/process">
                  <div class="custom-select">
                    <select id="product" name="product", method="GET" action="/">
                        {% for products in product %}
                            <option value = "{{products}}">{{products}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
  
  
                    </select>
  
                  </div>

                <label>Categories/NC</label>
                <div class="custom-select">
                  <select id="category" name="category">
                      {% for categories in category %}
                          <option value = "{{categories}}">{{categories}}</option>
                      {% endfor %}


                  </select>
                  
                </div>
                <div style="  position: absolute;
                bottom: 25px;
                right: 0px;">
                  <button type="submit">OK</button>
                  
                </div>
              </form>
              </div>
```

Comment: You didn't show the link of the button you're clicking on the frontend

Comment: In other words, none of the code you've shown is really relevant here because you're probably rendering a template with the wrong link built in

Comment: @roganjosh I had added my html code

Comment: I had tried change the link to my-app/process in the action, but when I click the button, it will direct me to my-app/my-app/process

Comment: `action = "{{ url_for('views.send_selection') }}"` I _think_. I don't use blueprints like this so I'm not sure how it knows to find `views` here

Comment: If that doesn't work, you still should be using some variant of [url_for](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.url_for) and not hard-coding in your templates